# Google Map marker Bouncing with flashing effect on Windows 8 machines

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Map marker Bouncing with flashing effect and this happens only in windows 8 machines. Is it possible to correct it?. I am currently using google map API 3 with **optimized: false;**

Code Snippet:

`marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latlng,

```
                    map: map,
                    optimized: false // stops the marker from flashing
                    });`
```

Comment: It would help to show us some code that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Please make sure your question has enough information to answer on it. Add some brief information, additional details. Share some source code if it involved.